# Is a class that is hard to unit test badly designed?

Tags: unit-testing

I am now doing unit testing on an application which was written over the year, before I started to do unit-testing diligently. I realized that the classes I wrote are hard to unit test, for the following reasons:

1. Relies on loading data from database. Which means I have to setup a row in the table just to run the unit test (and I am not testing database capabilities).
2. Requires a lot of other external classes just to get the class I am testing to its initial state.

On the whole, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the design except that it is too tightly coupled (which by itself is a bad thing). I figure that if I have written automated test cases with each of the class, hence ensuring that I don't heap extra dependencies or coupling for the class to work, the class might be better designed.

Does this reason holds water? What are your experiences?

Comment: sometimes it's not because of the design of your class, but mostly due to external environment : network for example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you are right. A class which is <strike>not unit testable</strike> hard to unit test is (almost always) not well designed (there are exceptions, as always, but these are rare - IMHO one should better not try to explain the problem away this way). Lack of unit tests means that it is harder to maintain - you have no way of knowing whether you have broken existing functionality whenever you modify anything in it.

Moreover, if it is (co)dependent with the rest of the program, any changes in it may break things even in seemingly unrelated, far away parts of the code.

TDD is not simply a way to test your code - it is also a different way of design. Effectively *using* - and thinking about using - your own classes and interfaces from the very first moment may result in a very different design than the traditional way of "code and pray". One concrete result is that typically most of your critical code is insulated from the boundaries of your system, i.e. there are wrappers/adapters in place to hide e.g. the concrete DB from the rest of the system, and the "interesting" (i.e. testable) code is not within these wrappers - these are as simple as possible - but in the rest of the system.

Now, if you have a bunch of code without unit tests and want to cover it, you have a challenge. Mocking frameworks may help a lot, but still it is a pain in the ass to write unit tests for such a code. A good source of techniques to deal with such issues (commonly known as *legacy code*) is [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052), by Michael Feathers.

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is... ?

Comment: ...disagreement with what you say.

Comment: @Pavel Gee, I wouldn't have guessed that ;-) Honestly, I would appreciate if you actually explained your point: that would give me a chance to _learn something new_ - the main reason I am here on SO.

Comment: @Péter, no offense, but you're 20 years older, sound confident and link authoritative sources.  How can I suppose you could learn from me?
Anyway, here it is: many classes heavily depend on environment, it's a fact.  A possible reason why they were created is decoupling the code into smaller chunks, so that these chunks are easier to maintain, and unit-testable!  But does it imply it would be *easy* to unit-test them?  It does not.  Your point of view also suggests that a big all-in-one class is better, while it really isn't.

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I could learn something from you indeed :-) In this case, it is that I did not communicate my opinion clearly enough. Writing good unit tests (in a real life project, that is) is not easy even under ideal circumstances. My point is simply that writing unit tests for legacy code is much more difficult. I am not sure what in my answer above suggests to you that I preferred big all-in-one classes - I do not, for many reasons. One of which is that IMO these are _more difficult_ to unit test than a bunch of small classes with a single reasponsibility each.

Comment: @Péter, well, the original question was about classes that are *hard to* unit test, not about classes that are *impossible* to (you were talking about the latter).  Perhaps, that was the source of misunderstanding.

Comment: @Pavel I see - my bad. Will fix it.

Comment: @Peter, I believe Feather says that if you can use extract method that doesn't use the dependencies, it can partially test a class. Not 100% code coverage but a start. So if mocking isn't an option extract method can go a long way. Also unit testing with dependencies is not necessarily a bad thing. The bad thing is having an enormous amount of setup or the dependency cannot be setup in a specific state; web server.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the design could be better with looser coupling, but ultimately you need data to test against.

You should look into Mocking frameworks to simulate the database and the other classes that this class relies on so you can have better control over the testing.

Answer (score 11):

I've found that [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is the design pattern that most helps make my code testable (and, often, also reusable and adaptable to contexts that are different from the original one that I had designed it for).  My Java-using colleagues adore [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/); I mostly program in Python, so I generally do my dependency injection "manually", since duck typing makes it easy; but it's the right fundamental DP for either static or dynamic languages (don't let me get started on "monkey patching"... let's just say it's not my favorite;-).

Once your class is ready to accept its dependencies "from the outside", instead of having them hard-coded, you can of course use fake or mock versions of the dependencies to make testing easier and faster to run -- but this also opens up other possibilities.  For example, if the state of the class as currently designed is complex and hard to set up, consider the [State design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern): you can refactor the design so that the state lives in a separate dependency (which you can set up and inject as desired) and the class itself is mostly responsible for behavior (updating the state).

Of course, by refactoring in this way, you'll be introducing more and more interfaces (abstract classes, if you're using C++) -- but that's perfectly all right: it's a excellent principle to "program to an interface, not an implementation".

So, to address your question directly, you're right: the difficulty in testing is definitely the design equivalent of what extreme programming calls a "code smell".  On the plus side, though, there's a pretty clear path to refactor this problem away -- you don't have to have a perfect design to start with (fortunately!-), but can enhance it as you go.  I'd recommend the book [Refactoring to Patterns](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/) as good guidance to this purpose.

Comment: Exactly. Inversion of Control (IoC) is the key here. Loose coupling will certainly help with unit testing but is not the sole reason to use it. It makes your code much more capable of handling changes which results in much higher level of maintainability.

Comment: Assuming you are allowed to use IoC...

Comment: *Metro Smurf* - could you say more? Who forbids IOC and why? (Speculation: if it's frameworks like Spring that are not allowed, you can do IOC without needing to use any framework...)

Answer (score 6):

For me, code should be **designed for testability**. The other way around, I consider non-testable or hard to test code as badly designed (regardless of its beauty).

In your case, maybe you can mock external dependencies to run real **unit tests** (in isolation).

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a different tack: the code just isn't designed for **testability**, but that does not mean its necessarily *badly designed*.  A design is the product of competing ***ilities**, of which **testability** is only one of them.  Every coding decision increases some of the ***itilies** while decreasing others.  For example, designing for **testability** generally harms its **simplicity/readability/understandability** (because it adds complexiety).  A *good* design favors the most important ***ilities** of your situation.

Your code isn't *bad*, it just maximizes the other ***ilities** other than **testability**. :-)

Update: Let me add this before I get accused of saying designing for ***testability** isn't important

The trick of course is to design and code to maximize the good ***ilities**, particularly the important ones.  Which ones are the important ones depends on your situation.  In my experience in my situations, designing for **testability** has been one of the more important ***ilities**.

Comment: The complexity added is minimal at best. In my experience, a class that is hard to test due to its coupling is also one that is hard to maintain and more fragile.

Comment: @John Nevertheless, the trade-off is there and I don't think we can say its minimal (minimal being relative as well) in every case.  I'm not arguing which *itities are or aren't important (coupling and maintainability *are* important).  I'm simply giving the asker a different point of view to consider: one or two characteristics does not good or bad code make.  Hopefully in the future, designing for testability is higher on his list.

Comment: Testable code tends to end up with several simple classes with distinct responsibilities and a more complicated object graph.  I.e. the parts are simpler but the interactions are more complicated.  I find it easier to reason about this than 'fat' classes, though.  Some developers will argue the other way.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I just disagree with it :). I don't write my code in a way that makes it testable just so I can test it. I do it because it makes my code more maintainable (Separation of Concerns), more resilient to change, and easier to build upon. Testability is just a nice side effect.

Comment: I have to second @john's opinion. I don't write code for testability. My unit tests are written using Test Driven Design, not Test Driven Testability. Having regression tests after 'designing' my code is just a beneficial side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a way to establish if a class is "well designed" or not, at least the first thing you mention is usually a sign of a questionable design.

Instead of relying on the database, the class you are testing should have a dependency on an object whose only responsibility is getting that data, maybe using a pattern like Repository or DAO.

As for the second reason, it doesn't necessarily highlight a bad design of the class; it can be a problem with the design of the tests (not having a fixture supertype or helpers where you can setup the dependencies used in several tests) and/or the overall architecture (i.e. not using factories or inversion of control to inject the corresponding dependencies)

Also, you probably shouldn't be using "real" objects for your dependencies, but test doubles. This helps you make sure you are testing the behavior of that one class, and not that of its dependencies. I suggest you look into mocking frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the large majority of your classes will be unit-testable, but you'll never get to 100% since you're bound to have at least one bit that is dedicated to binding the other classes together to an overall program. (It's best if that can be exactly one place that is obviously and trivially correct, but not all code is as pleasant to work with.)

Answer (score 0):

I ***might*** have an ideal solution for you to consider... the Private Accessor

Recently I served in a role where we used them prolifically to avoid the very situation you're describing -- reliance upon artificial data maintained within the primary data-store.

While not the simplest technology to implement, after doing so you'll be able to easily hard-define private members in the method being tested to whatever conditions you feel they should possess, and right from the unit-test code (so no loading from the database).  Also you'll have accomplished the goal without violating class protection levels.

Then it's basic assert & verification for desired conditions as normal.